# rails - combining two columns in the db into one in signup form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I have two columns in the db `:first_name` and `:last_name`.
In the signup form I want to have only one field `:full_name`.

Name model (doesn't have a table in the db):

```
class Name
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name, @last_name = first_name, last_name
end
def to_s
    "#@first_name #@last_name"
end 
end
```

Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 def name
 @name ||= Name.new(first_name, last_name)

end

def name=(name)
 self[:first_name] = name.first_name
 self[:last_name] = name.last_name
 @name = name
end     

end
```

view:

```
= f.input :name, label: false, required: true, autofocus: true,      placeholder: "Full Name"
```

Comment: What is the problem you do have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the `Name` model, you just need a virtual attribute. BTW, this code was taken from Railscasts 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes?view=asciicast

```
# Getter
  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end

  # Setter
  def full_name=(name)
    split = name.split(' ', 2)
    self.first_name = split.first
    self.last_name = split.last
  end
```